# Magento - routing to paypal IPN script

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a multi language site and am having Magento (1.7.0.2) "Add Store Code to Urls" (config/system/web).

I have overridden the `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal` with my own `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal` as I have added extra backend functionality.

I can hit the IPN scripts manually (as expected) through the URL by going to:
`mysite.com/uk/paypal/ipn/` in the browser (which shows as a GET request in my apache access log, with a 200 status). However when paypal posts to the same URL (which shows as a POST request in the log) it results in a 404.

I don't understand why there is a difference in GET and POST to this URL but maybe it is something to do with Magento's routing?

Anyway, what can I do so that the IPN script can be hit by paypal, and I can still use store codes in the URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After logging each class method I found that Magneto was trying to load a website with `$scopeCode` = 'us' in `run()` method in `/var/www/simplesteps/site/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php`.

This is a throw-back to the time when we have a USA website, but this website had been removed, yet a reference to it was being used.

I am not sure where this reference was being set, after looking through CMS settings I could not find it. If anyone could tell me I'd appreciate that.

I fixed the issue by reinstating the USA website, which, it turns out should not have been removed.

The reason the IPN script was being correctly hit through the browser URL (GET 200) but not paypal (POST 404) is probably to do with it being called within the scope of the active website via the URL, and not a default or legacy reference to US site.

Hope this helps someone who may find a similar frustrating situation.